# Proper way to extend model classes in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, monkeypatching

Assume we want to build two independent Django applications:

- for voting
- for commenting

Any of these features can be plugged to any existing Django model. For instance we could want to enable voting and commenting on model `Article`.

But what if we want to enable voting on comments? `Comment` model would depend on voting app. And what if we want to use comments only, without the voting app at all? It won't work because of the dependency.

So, enabling voting should be done **outside** models definitions, right? In settings, for example. And now, how can I dynamically extend these existing models without modifying their code?

After some research I found `add_to_class` method, but it seems using it is considered bad development practise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to make this functionality parts of the models at all? Usually these would be separate apps, with models that have relationships to articles. You can use [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) to define a database relationship between your comment or voting app and the target models.

Comment: I would like to add some functionality to models. For instance `Article.votes.get_score()`

Comment: But that's functionality on the Vote class, not on the article.

Comment: Still, the `Article` would have to have `votes` defined. I cannot do that without modifying `Article` code.

Comment: But that's my whole point. `votes` is a reverse relationship, which is added by the contributing app, via a ForeignKey or generic relation.